# How to change my code to work Captcha after redirecting

Tags: php, captcha

I'm changing my website codes. I'm using routing system then I'm redirecting all request to index.php file by htaccess file. now my captcha image doesn't work.

captcha generator:

```
 <?php
  session_start();
  //Send a generated image to the browser 
  create_image(); 
  exit();

 header("Content-type: image/png");
 function create_image(){
 $x = 98;
 $y = 45;
 $im = imagecreate($x,$y);
 $bgcolor=imagecolorallocate($im,13,17,25);


 $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im,255, 255, 210);

function rand_string( $length ) {
$chars = "abcdklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEF0123456789GHIJKefghijLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"; 
$str ="";
$size = strlen( $chars );
for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
    $str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
}

   return $str;
}

 $text=rand_string(rand(1,2));
 $_SESSION['security_code']=strtolower($text);

 imagettftext($im, 24, 3, 2, 32, $text_color, "fonts/grade.ttf", $text);
 $color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255,222, 255);


for($i =2; $i < 55; $i+=mt_rand(2,6)) {
  for($j =4; $j < 45; $j+=mt_rand(1,5)) {
  
    imagesetpixel($im, $i,$j, $color);
 }

  } 
        
  imagejpeg($im);
  imagedestroy($im);
  }
?>
```

html code to show captcha image:

```
 <img id="imgCaptcha" src="Captcha.php" style="float: right;" />
```

htaccess rewrite to redirect:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

how to change my code to show my captcha image after redirecting?

Comment: remove `exit()` and try once again, code stops execution after `exit()`

Comment: no , it's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:

```
  imagettftext($im, 24, 3, 2, 32, $text_color, "fonts/grade.ttf", $text);
```

it could not find the font file.
I replace the relative path with absolute path:

```
$font= __DIR__.'/fonts/grade.ttf';
imagettftext($im, 24, 3, 2, 32, $text_color, $font, $text);
```